# What set is produced from $a^* \cup b^*$?

Tags: formal-languages

I'm trying to construct an enumerating Turing Machine to recognize $a^* \cup b^*$ (* is Kleene star) and I'm unsure if the set I'm making the TM recognize is the correct one.

I think it is:
$$\emptyset, a, b, aa, bb, aaa, bbb, aaaa, bbbb,\ldots$$ and so on.

Can anyone confirm if I am correct? If not, what should it be?

Comment: What is a "TM" and why wouldn't you spell it out, and why do you think everyone in mathematics who could help knows this?  *Turing machine*?  (Only a small percentage of mathematicians would recognize this use.)

Comment: @David G. Stork I apologize, will change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are using is the Kleene star, then your description is correct. It is the union of the two languages $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ contains strings with zero or more a's, and $B$ contains strings with zero or more b's.

Comment: It was a Kleene star, thank you!